# How to find this angle? triangle

Tags: triangles

[Triangle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j6b2.jpg)
[image]

How do I find $\angle\,\text{BCD}$? We know that $\text{AD} =\text{BC}$.

I just don't know how to find $\angle\,\text{BCD}$. I tried using parallel line but I just can't.

Comment: You have seen that AB and AC is of equal length?

Comment: sorry I don't what to call it when 2 side of a triangle is the same length.
My English is not good

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: That is given by the context, at least in this case as the triangle is a isosceles triangle. You marked it right with your - in the sides of your triangle. I just wanted to check that you saw that fact.

Comment: It's not a homework, though. I found this in some kind of Engineering test today. None of my friend can give answer to this. :(

Comment: It's okay to ask homework questions, just add what you have tried with and it will be okay. Sorry if I expressed myself a bit clumsy.

Comment: Would you like to include a picture or link to this test? I'm interested.

Comment: There's no link. It's a part of a Chulalongkorn University in Thailand Engineering event. They let us take the test home but it's all written in Thai. I'm afraid that I can't translate it well into English.

Answer (score 1):

let $$AD=x$$ and the angle $$BCD=y$$ then we get after the Theorem of sines $$\frac{\sin(100^{\circ}-y)}{\sin(80^{\circ})}=\frac{\sin(80^{\circ}-y)}{\sin(20^{\circ})}$$
can you solve this?

Comment: What is it for kind of of rule that you are using here? I'm used to $\frac{\sin(A^{\circ})}{b}=\frac{\sin(B^{\circ})}{b}=\frac{\sin(C^{\circ})}{c}.$

Comment: I found what you've done.

Comment: Sorry, I can't.